Analytic continuation of a contour integral involving a double pole
How can it be shown that the function $\operatorname{f}\left(z\right)$, defined as a contour integral, can be analytically continued to the region $D$ ?:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{f}\left(z\right) & =
\int_{\left\vert\,\xi\,\right\vert\ =\ 2} \frac{\cos\left(\xi + 1/\xi\right)}
{\xi^{2} + 1}
\frac{{\rm d}\xi}{\left(\xi - z\right)^{2}}\,, \quad\left\vert\, z\,\right\vert > 2
\\[3mm] \mbox{and}\ D & = \left\{z \not = 0, {\rm i}, -{\rm i}\right\}
\end{align}

Welcome to Math StackExchange. Please spend time reading about how to ask a good question on Math StackExchange and update your question accordingly. Here we expect asker to include his/her work/effort on solving the problem.

Have you tried obtaining a closed form for $f$ when $|z|>2$? Hopefully, it will be obvious which analytic function of domain $D$ extends it.

Have you come across the Residue Theorem yet?

Use Cauchy's formula:
$$f(z)\ = \ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_C \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi -z} \ d\xi$$
$$f'(z) \ =\ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \ \frac{d}{dz}\int_C \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi -z} \ d\xi \ = \ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\ \int_C \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi -z)^2} \ d\xi $$
to identify
$$ 2 \pi i \ f(z) =   \frac{\cos\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)}{z^2 + 1} $$
